# How can I extend the system partition in Windows 10 with a Red Hat VirtIO SCSI Disk Device?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, disk-management, openstack

I use OpenStack to spawn virtual servers. I launched a new virtual server that runs on Microsoft Windows 10. Afterward, I attach to it 300GB of extra storage space, in the shape of a Red Hat VirtIO SCSI Disk Device. How can I extend the system partition in Windows 10 with a Red Hat VirtIO SCSI Disk Device?

When I go to the `Disk Management` in the virtual server running Microsoft Windows 10, I see:

[image]

where Disk 2 is the  Red Hat VirtIO SCSI Disk Device.

The `Extend Volume`option  on Disk 0 is greyed out:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your disks are dynamic which means volume can't go behind disk limit.

Make disks dynamic first then you should be able to extend it.

Comment: With this additional side-note: The extra disk must be visible to the Bios or UEFI at boot-time. If it is NOT visible there (AKA needs a driver in Windows for it to be accessible) you can't  extend the OS partition to it.  If it can be accessed by a UEFI driver that is loaded by UEFI before Windows is started it should also be possible to use as part of the system drive. I have never seen that working, or even heard of someone who tried it, but in theory it should be possible.